# External USB HDD with powered usb hub

Tags: usb-power

Please has somebody some idea how to fix what I described at http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=47218&p=546350#p546350?

It worked yesterday and today I attached a Nexus 7 to charge from the hub and from that moment Pi can't spin up the USB HDD. 
Upgraded firmware today also.

Comment: Can you check the voltages on the +5 to GND pins on the Pi and also on one of the other USB ports of the powered hub (the two outermost pins of the connector)?

Comment: Measured according to this http://suniljohn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/RPI_Test_Points.jpg - http://www.siongboon.com/projects/2013-07-08_raspberry_pi/images/power%20measuring%20with%20power%20adaptor%201.JPG but zero => http://youtu.be/1n1ig7d3dy4